# Button function in customized JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame in which I have customized my buttons in an order fashion favorable to my preference. It looks like this: [Menu for Traverse Operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSngr.png)

What operation should I use in my ActionListener Class to call the button I have declared? I have three JButtons declared but I only called one button on the ActionListener class to show the error. The error is the (e.getSource == b1). Dunno what to replace that cause that line works in my JPanel class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class FeedTheDogMenu extends JFrame{
    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Operation Menu");

    Selection handle;
    FeedTheDogMenu(){
        handle = new Selection();

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Forward Traverse");
        b1.setBounds(20, 30, 150, 25);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Backward Traverse");
        b2.setBounds(20, 60, 150, 25);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("Random Traverse");
        b3.setBounds(20, 90, 150, 25);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(25, 10, 450, 15);
        label.setText("Choose an operation: ");

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
        l1.setBounds(195, 28, 200, 15);
        l1.setText("In this menu, you will be");

        JLabel l2 = new JLabel();
        l2.setBounds(195, 46, 200, 15);
        l2.setText("able to witness three");

        JLabel l3 = new JLabel();
        l3.setBounds(195, 64, 200, 15);
        l3.setText("different operations");

        JLabel l4 = new JLabel();
        l4.setBounds(195, 82, 200, 15);
        l4.setText("in which the agent will");

        JLabel l5 = new JLabel();
        l5.setBounds(195, 100, 200, 15);
        l5.setText("perform to find the dog.");

        JLabel author = new JLabel();
        author.setBounds(23, 160, 200, 15);
        author.setText("Feed the Dog v 0.1.3");

        JLabel pow = new JLabel();
        pow.setBounds(23, 173, 200, 15);
        pow.setText("Powered by BlueJ");

        JLabel intelprop = new JLabel();
        intelprop.setBounds(190, 173, 170, 15);
        intelprop.setText("(c) 2018, James Vausch");

        f.add(b1);
        f.add(b2);
        f.add(b3);
        f.add(label);
        f.add(l1);
        f.add(l2);
        f.add(l3);
        f.add(l4);
        f.add(l5);
        f.add(author);
        f.add(pow);
        f.add(intelprop);

        f.setSize(380,235);
        f.setLocation(150, 150);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        b1.addActionListener(handle);
        b2.addActionListener(handle);
        b3.addActionListener(handle);

        add(f, handle);
    }

    class Selection implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if ("Forward Traverse".equals(e.getSource())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
                FeedOp feed = new FeedOp();
                feed.display();
                feed.assignDog();
                feed.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }

            if (e.getSource() == b1) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be a great help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("Forward Traverse");
```

The "b1" variable is defined as a local variable, so it can only be referenced in the method where it is defined.

If you want the ActionListener to be able to reference the variable then you need to define it as an instance variable of the class (the same way you define the "handle" variable).

Also:

```
if ("Forward Traverse".equals(e.getSource())) {
```

That code will do nothing because the getSource() method doesn't return a String. Read the API for the `ActionEvent`.